# How to fill table rows using context of views.py on page load?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am working on a django project and I ran into a bit of a problem and not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Problem**

The user clicks on a cell on a page "userlist/". I save the value of username in localstorage in Javascript and take user to another page "maclists". On "maclists" I run POST using fetch of javascript and POST the stored username to views.py. I am able to retrieve the values as I want. Though they are as queryset objects like this:

> <QuerySet [(1, '828234y8y', 'hn', 'hbhb', 'bhjh', 'hbj'), (2, '9299338uu8u', 'hbhb', 'hbhb', 'bhb', 'bhbh')]>

I convert them to list of dictionaries and I finally have something like this:

> [{'machineid': '828234y8y', 'machinename': 'hn', 'protocol': 'hbhb', 'port': 'bhjh', 'targetip': 'hbj'}, {'machineid': '9299338uu8u', 'machinename': 'hbhb', 'protocol': 'hbhb', 'port': 'bhb', 'targetip': 'bhbh'}]

Then I try to send it to the "maclists" page using :

```
return render(request, "users/maclists.html", {'machines': listsofmac})
```

listsofmac stores the above list of dictionaries.
The issue is I don't see the data in table of HTML using the context I passed. I don't know if it is due to the thing that I used POST at windows.load().

**Help required**

Any suggestion or alternative to show the data when "maclists" loads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Your template ***maclists.html***, loop through **machines** and print the values. This way

```
{% for machine in machines %}
{{machine.machineid}}
{{machine.machinename}}
{% endfor %}
```